# Bad Sphinx :linenos: alignment

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

Line numbers are not aligned in Sphinx's Read The Docs Theme.

The highlighted lines are **5** and **8**.

[image]

The restructured text which produced this:

```
.. code-block:: python
    :emphasize-lines: 5, 8
    :linenos:
```

Thoughts on why this might be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce the problem with sphinx_rtd_theme 0.2.4. It has been fixed in the master branch: https://github.com/rtfd/sphinx_rtd_theme/issues/381.

Commit (8 March 2017): https://github.com/rtfd/sphinx_rtd_theme/pull/382/commits/deb553c1d2da7a74c56ab825353522c98d2e9093.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up going with the sphinx guzzle theme which I found much cleaner than RTD - https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle_sphinx_theme